# Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vb.net, winforms

m getting an error while using
Text1.SetFocus
the error is
invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Remove this line and set the TabIndex of Text1 to 0.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some code for us to review, so we can see it in context?  Is this vb6?

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling this from a module, i.e. not from the form code, you need to reference the form object where text1 lays.
The other thing you may need to do is to get some persistency pills, hit F1 more often and use words in abundance when asking for help.

Comment: You gotta take the pills first, but that's the proper wording. The answer would be "Yes, I can. Bye."

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference Text1.SetFocus from Form_Activate and no from Form_Load -

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-forms-vb6-tutorial

Form_Load vs. Form_Activate

In the Form_Load event, you would typically perform initialization-type tasks, as you should. However, certain types of actions cannot be performed in the Load event, due to the fact that the form is fully loaded only after the Load event completes. For one thing, printing to the form will not work when done in the Load event. In addition, if you try to set focus to a particular control on the form during the Load event, you will get the message Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. For example, assume you had a textbox called Text1 on the form. The following code would result in that error:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

' other initialization stuff

Text1.SetFocus ' causes an error

End Sub
```

The reason for the error is that since the form is not fully loaded, neither are any of the controls on it â€“ and you can't set focus to a control that is not yet available.
To remedy this problem, you should use one of the other Form events, such as the Activate event. (When VB loads a form, it actually cycles through a number of events, such as: Initialize, Load, Resize, Activate, GotFocus, and Paint. Of these, Load and Activate are probably the ones most commonly used. ) Placing the code to set focus to a control will work in the Form_Activate event:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

' other statements

Text1.SetFocus ' no problem here

End Sub
```

A caution about the activate event: it will fire whenever your application switches to that form. For example, if you switch back and forth between Form1 and Form2, be aware that any code you might have in the Activate events for these forms will be executed when you switch to that form. Therefore, if you have code in the Activate event that you only want to execute "the first time", you will need to control execution with a Boolean switch. For example, in the General Declarations of your form you could define the following variable:

```
Private mblnFormActivated As Boolean ' will be initialized to False by default
```

You can then use this switch in the Activate event as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

If mblnFormActivated Then Exit Sub

' statements you only want to execute once, including the following
' statement to turn the switch on:

mblnFormActivated = True

End Sub
```